# Sitecore 8: Experience Profile not calculating Value (Latest visit) properly

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-analytics

Sitecore Experience profile (EXP) responsible to record user visits and calculates the values related to the actions that the visitor did on the website.
In our website, Sitecore EXP records the user visits but the visit values are not properly being calculated.

Value (Latest visit) fields shows 0 for some visitors.

[image]

But when I go inside the visitor details it populates the visitor values in the Goals section in the Activity tab.

[image]

I have rebuild the Sitecore analytics database as well.

Comment: Have you created a support ticket?

Comment: Not yet. Do you think this is a Sitecore issue ?

Comment: @PrageethRoshane yep it is a known issue for Sitecore 8 recently.