# Sitecore 8: How the Value (Total) getting calculated in Experience Profile?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I'm having trouble with the Value (Total) field in the Sitecore Experience Profile. How is this calculated ?

[image]

According to the image I'm getting the value in the Value (Total) as 70. But when I go inside to that profile the sum of the Total value field is more than 70.
Doesn't it suppose to match to the amount that display in the Value (Total) field in the Experience Profile Dashboard?

Comment: What is the difference between this question and your [**previous question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33668778/)?

Comment: In previous question, it is about the Value (Latest visit). Which is the value achieved by the visitor in his/her last visit. This is about the total value of the visitor in his/her total visits. According to the information in the attached image, total showing as 70. But should it be 170 ? Am I reading this correct ?

Comment: You are correct, Prageeth. The total value should be 170. I have had the same problem and submitted a support ticket to Sitecore. You should do the same.
They haven't replied to me with anything definitive yet, though. By the way, I do believe that this issue roots from the same cause as the issue in your previous question.